# How to publish google apps script to cloud for public?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a apps script that uses bigquery service to fetch data from my bigquery account and builds visualizations/tables etc. I publish the app with following options
Execute App as: User accessing web app
Who has access to this app: Anyone

1. When I open the link (one ending in exec not dev) in chrome incognito, I expect it to show the web app but it asks for google credentials.
2. When I entering credentials of my other (different from the one hosting the project) account, I get a permissions error.
3. I added this other account from my primary one under permissions option of google console - even that wasn't enough.
4. I had to create a dummy project as this other user to accept the invitation from my primary account. After that the app showed up on this other account.

My question is, how do I publish my app for the consumers (even public) of this info without them having to create dummy project/accept my invite etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors:
1) Publish to run as **you** not the user, and
2) make it anonymous access. *
People might consume your daily/per second quotas thou.

(*) anonymous access option might not be present if the google apps administrator disabled anonymous sharing in the console.